# LINQ to Entites join on ID or null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a LINQ to Entities statement that joins two models on an AlphaGroupID, like this:

```
IEnumerable<ICD.ViewModels.HomeSearchViewModel> ICDList = (from a in ICDUnitOfWork.AlphaGroups.Find()
                                                                       join e in ICDUnitOfWork.Alphas.Find()
                                                                       on a.AlphaGroupID equals e.AlphaGroupID)
```

I need to join the two tables on AlphaGroupID, but I also need all of the ICDUnitOfWork.AlphaGroups regardless of whether or not they have a corresponding AlphaGroupID in ICDList.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `join into` (it is same as GroupJoin):

```
var query = from a in ICDUnitOfWork.AlphaGroups.Find()
            join e in ICDUnitOfWork.Alphas.Find()
                   on a.AlphaGroupID equals e.AlphaGroupID into g
            select new { AlphaGroup = a, Alphas = g };
```

GroupJoin produces hierarchical result - for each item in outer sequence will be generated sequence of corresponding items in inner sequence (sequence could be empty).